# UNIX Shell-scripting: UDV

Tags: unix, shell

I am writing a simple unix shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                  

# abort the script if a command fails
set -e

# abort the script if an unitialized shell variable is used
set -u

i = 0;
while [$i -l 1]
do
  src/meshpro input/martini.off video/noise/image$i.off -noise $i
  src/meshview video/noise/image$i.off -output_image video/noise/image$i.jpg -exit_immediately
  i='expr $i + 0.1'
done
```

When I try to run the script, I get the following error: `line 14: i: command not found`. I used a tutorial to apply to my code. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put spaces around the equal sign, and you don't need the semicolon:

```
i=0
```

Also, you have quite a few other errors in the script.

Comment: am I allowed to increment by something other than an integer value, like I'm doing with my variable i?

Comment: Yes, but not with `expr`. Try `bc` instead.

Comment: thanks =) I tried bc (i='bc $i + 0.01'), but I get a line 10: [: too many arguments
error at the second run of the while loop.

Comment: Yes, because 1) you're performing command substitution incorrectly, and 2) you're not quoting properly.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces hurts. Put

```
i=0;
```

not

```
i = 0;
```

With spaces i is interpreted as command, not as assignement.

Comment: There are other spacing problems in the code - and the semicolon is not necessary.

Comment: Not necessary is different from wrong, and one error at time :)

Answer (score 2):

If using normal assignment, no spaces are allowed so you need:

```
i=0
```

(note that the semicolon is unnecessary). If you really want nicely formatted expressions, you can use the:

```
((i = 0))
```

statement. I would also use it in place of `expr` as well since `expr` is an external command with all the cost of process creation (this usually doesn't matter for quick and dirty scripts where only a few external processes are created but, if you find it happening a lot, you can get a very decent performance improvement).

Unfortunately, it doesn't like floating point but you can easily emulate it in your case since your numbers simply range from `0.0` through `0.9` (i.e., only the fractional part changes):

```
((i = i + 1))
```

and running it from 0 to 9, modifying the other lines to suit the new range.

The only other thing I'd check would be:

```
while [$i -l 1]
```

I think `[` is treated as a command so you may need spaces (and you *definitely* need a real comparison operator):

```
while [ $i -lt 1 ]
```

And `[` is typically also an external program, I prefer the `bash` built in `[[`.

Tying all those elements together:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                  
set -e
set -u

((i = 0))
while [[ $i -lt 10 ]] ; do
    src/meshpro input/martini.off video/noise/image0.$i.off -noise 0.$i
    src/meshview video/noise/image$i.off -output_image \
        video/noise/image0.$i.jpg -exit_immediately
    ((i = i + 1))
done
```

You'll notice a difference with the output in that previously your zero file would have been `image0.off` with the others `image0.X.off`, whereas now it's `image0.0.off`. I think that's beneficial as well since it gives all your files exactly the same format.

If you disagree, it would be a simple matter to add:

```
mv video/noise/image0.0.jpg video/noise/image0.jpg
```

to the end of your script.

Comment: re: [ vs [[ and [ being a command: style-wise, I really prefer using 'test' to '['.  No one will ever make the mistake of writing 'while test$i -lt 1', but 'while [$i -lt 1]' seems to be an oft repeated mistake.  Side note: both [ and test have been bash builtins for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

the `expr` is wrong. AFAIK it doesn't handle decimal. And `i = 0` is wrong as well. no space around `=` sign.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                  
set -e
set -u
i=0;
while true
do
  src/meshpro input/martini.off video/noise/image$i.off -noise $i
  src/meshview video/noise/image$i.off -output_image video/noise/image$i.jpg -exit_immediately
  i=$(echo "scale=2;$i + 0.1"|bc)
  case $i in 1.*) break ; esac
done
```